# How to group Array of Dictionaries by a key in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

For example, I have this array of dictionaries

```
 [["Country":"Egypt","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"],["Country":"Palestine","Name":"Omar","Age":"15"],["Country":"Egypt","Name":"Ali","Age":"40"],["Country":"Jordan","Name":"Ahmad","Age":"25"],["Country":"Palestine","Name":"Amani","Age":"30"],["Country":"Jordan","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"]]
```

I want to group them by Country to become

```
  {"Egypt": [{"Country":"Egypt","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"} {"Country":"Egypt","Name":"Ali","Age":"40"}],
   "Palestine": [{"Country":"Palestine","Name":"Amani","Age":"30"},{"Country":"Palestine","Name":"Omar","Age":"15"}],
   "Jordan":[{"Country":"Jordan","Name":"Ahmad","Age":"25"},{"Country":"Jordan","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"}]
}
```

Please help.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Dictionaries are an inappropriate data structure to be using for a set of statically known keys – you should use a custom struct instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift has a nice function that does this for you...

```
let people = [["Country":"Egypt","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"],["Country":"Palestine","Name":"Omar","Age":"15"],["Country":"Egypt","Name":"Ali","Age":"40"],["Country":"Jordan","Name":"Ahmad","Age":"25"],["Country":"Palestine","Name":"Amani","Age":"30"],["Country":"Jordan","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"]]

let peopleByCountry = Dictionary(grouping: people, by: { $0["Country"]! } )
```

`peopleByCountry` will now be the format that you want.

You can read more about this function [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init).

Just to add to Hamish's comment.

You really shouldn't be working with Dictionaries here. You should be working with Structs...

```
struct Person {
    let countryName: String
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Even better would be to have a `Country` struct...

```
struct Country {
    let name: String
}
```

and use that in the `Person` for their `country` property instead of `String`.

Comment: I will gonna delete my poor answer :| as this one is the latest solution.

Comment: @mustafa that’s a lot of question. Haha. When you’ve studied computer science for a couple of years come back and you will have your answer. 

Comment: @Fogmeister Can u send me the same for objective c.

Comment: @Grigo if you have a new question then the best method is to ask a new question. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

```
let arrCountry: [[String:String]] = [["Country":"Egypt","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"],
                  ["Country":"Palestine","Name":"Omar","Age":"15"],
                  ["Country":"Egypt","Name":"Ali","Age":"40"],
                  ["Country":"Jordan","Name":"Ahmad","Age":"25"],
                  ["Country":"Palestine","Name":"Amani","Age":"30"],
                  ["Country":"Jordan","Name":"Mustafa","Age":"20"]]

func sortCountry() {
    var sortedCountries : [String : [[String:String]]] = [:]
    for object in arrCountry {
        let country = object["Country"] as! String
        if var arrCountry = sortedCountries[country] {
            arrCountry.append(object)
            sortedCountries[country] =  arrCountry
        }
        else {
            sortedCountries[country] =  [object]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I would go like this:

1. Get all the countries by traversing the array once and store it in an array.
2. Loop for this array of countries.
3. Filter the array with predicate where country is current country.
4. Store this in the final dictionary of country.

Comment: If you were going to do this manually you could doo all this in one run through of the array. Create a `[String: Array]` `grouped` dictionary. Loop through array. Get `country` from each element. Get array from `grouped` with key of the country (or `[]` if nil) and add dictionary to it. Takes it from worst case `O(n^2)` in your case to `O(n)` in mine.