# Swift - Convert Array to Dictionary Based on Custom Condition

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

If I have an array of objects of the form:

```
[{ userId: 3, data: "bla bla"} , { userId: 2, data: "bla bla"}, { userId: 3, data: "bla bla2"}, { userId: 1, data: "bla bla"}, { userId: 1, data: "bla bla2"}]
```

I can convert this to a dictionary with the keys being the `userId` as follows:

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: myData, by: {$0.userId})
```

but what if I know that my user has the `userId` `3` and I want to create a dictionary like this:

```
{
   key: "me",
   value: [{ userId: 3, data: "bla bla"},{ userId: 3, data: "bla bla2"}], 
   key: "others", 
   value: [{ userId: 2, data: "bla bla"}, { userId: 1, data: "bla bla"}, { userId: 1, data: "bla bla2"}]
}
```

Comment: You can't have twice the same key in a dictionary, they are uniques. So "key: me" and "key others", that's strange... Did you mean: `["me": [arrayOfDictWhereUserIdIs3], "others": [arrayOfDictWhereUserIdIsNOT3]]`?

Comment: @Larme that's exactly what I meant

Comment: Do it manually I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729936/how-to-group-array-of-dictionaries-by-a-key-in-swift ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grouping:by:` can *still* help here! The key would be either `"me"` or `"others"`

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: myData, by: {$0.userId == 3 ? "me" : "others"})
```